# std::ofstream does not open file

Tags: c++, file-io, ubuntu-12.04, iostream, ofstream

I'm writing the server backend of an iOS app now. The server needs to create an empty .caf file in a new directory as part of setting up a new game on request from a client. I use this code to create the file:

```
std::string gameIDdir = "mkdir " + std::to_string(current+1);
std::string absoluteFilePath = (std::to_string(current+1) + "/sound.caf");

std::cout << "made dir: " << std::to_string(current+1) << std::endl;
std::cout << "absoluteFilePath is " << std::to_string(current+1) + "/sound.caf" << std::endl;

std::ofstream file;
file.open(absoluteFilePath, std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);

std::cout << "opened absoluteFilePath. Open? " << file.is_open() << std::endl;

file << 0x00;

file.close();
```

Where the couts are obviously there for debugging purposes. The last cout always prints

> Open? 0

for reasons I don't know. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? I am running the program with sudo/root user on Ubuntu Server through SSH.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would advise your server app not to run as root. If it is neccesary create a specific user and or group. Make that user run the server. That avoids breaking your server when something nasty happens on the server.

Comment: where do you create the folder? do the path exist?